# React-native iOS how to get users Steam Id

Tags: node.js, react-native, passport.js, steam

I am attempting to have an react-native ios application (and a node.js server using passport) that uses the steam developer API which requires login with OpenId.

I am using this passport library https://github.com/liamcurry/passport-steam

In the examples using a web app, the user clicks a link and is essentially redirected to a steam webpage to login, and then is redirected back to the app after logging in.

Using React-Native for iOS is it possible to reproduce this same behavior? Essentially opening safari, letting the user login, and then redirecting back to the app and passing the users steamID back to the app?

The only goal of the login is to get the users steamID.

Update:
I was able to successfully link to the steam login using the information on the react-native docs here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html
However, the missing link is linking back to the app.